# Can you get autographs of the Baseball HOF inductees?

Tags: baseball, hall-of-fame

I'll be going to the Baseball Hall of Fame induction ceremonies in a few days, and would like to understand how they handle autographs.

Do the inductees give autographs? For free or for a cost? Or does it vary depending on who the inductees are?

Comment: I don't think I understand the downvotes on this question.  It's sports fandom related (which perhaps is why?), but it otherwise is asking a very specific question that is quite answerable.  I've taken out the irrelevant parts in the first paragraph to focus it some, perhaps that's sufficient?